# Compare URLs from two different text files Python

Tags: python, compare

I have a text file (links.txt) in the following format:

```
www.independent.co.uk www.bbc.co.uk www.theguardian.com www.telegraph.co.uk 
www.dailymail.co.uk en.wikipedia.org www.huffingtonpost.co.uk www.bbc.co.uk 
www.newsnow.co.uk www.express.co.uk
```

I have another text file (keys.txt) in the following format:

```
www.independent.co.uk www.bbc.co.uk www.theguardian.com
```

I want to compare both the text files and the URLs that are common in both the files has to be printed

I tried using the urltools package in python but couldn't do it for multiple urls

Comment: Please, post what have you tried

Comment: Those two files seem to be the same "format", ie a space-separated list of domains. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same format. I want to see if the urls in keys.txt are existing in links.txt. If they exist then it has to print that specific url.

Comment: I used urltools.compare which compares 2 urls and tells whether they match or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
links = open('links.txt', 'r')
links_data = links.read()
links.close()

keys = open('keys.txt', 'r')
keys_data = keys.read()
keys.close()

keys_split = keys_data.split()

for url in keys_split:
    if url in links_data:
        print(url)
```

Just make sure that `links.txt` and `keys.txt` are in the current working directory and everything should work fine.  I'm assuming your URLs will always be space-delimited.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks! @agillgilla

Comment: No problem.  Please mark it as the accepted answer if it answered your question  @clawstack.

Answer (score 0):

To print only unique URL instead common URL, just modify condition `not in`, here is complete code -

```py
links = open('links.txt', 'r')
links_data = links.read()
links.close()

keys = open('keys.txt', 'r')
keys_data = keys.read()
keys.close()

keys_split = keys_data.split()

for url in keys_split:
    if url not in links_data:
        print(url)
```